# PDF - why is there no standard structure element for a page?

Tags: pdf, structure

The [PDF Spec](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/pdf/PDFReference16.pdf) defines standard structure types, used to define a structure tree for the document. As far as I can see, there is no element related to pages. Here are the standard structure types for grouping elements:

```
Document
Part
Art
Sect
Div
...and so on...
```

Why is there no Page item in this list?

If you want your structure to use pages, what should be used? Part? Sect? Div?

Comment: It would probably help to note that this is for grouping PDF structure elements which were tagged and a "Grouped Element" and shouldn't be confused with the "Document Structure" itself. From the PDF spec: _Grouping elements are used solely to group other structure elements; they are not directly associated with content items. Table 10.20 describes the standard structure types for elements in this category. Section G.7, “Structured Elements That Describe Hierarchical Lists” provides an example of nested table of content items._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDF tags exist so that the content type / meaning of elements can be identified. They should be considering a kind of "meta" information for the PDF, simply providing context for the content in a file (so that content can be easily extracted, converted, processed, accessible, etc.). Think of it as a table of contents to a book. Just because the book has x pages doesn't mean that the content structure would be altered if the book's page height was cut in half and now had 2x pages in it.

A Page Object in the PDF Document Structure already groups elements (by nature of each element being on a given page), so doing so in this structure would be a little redundant.

Also, consider this case:

- Document

  - Table of Contents (Page 1)
  - Section 1 (starts on page 2, ends mid page 3)

    1. Sub Section (page 2)
    2. Sub Section (half of page 3)
  - Section 2 (starts mid page 3)

etc...

In this example, Section 1 and Section 2 couldn't both be direct parents of page 3 (not to mention that Section 1 spans two different pages). Additionally, trying to solve this problem really isn't necessary because the elements which is being grouped here is already each a child of its respective Document Structure's Page node in the actual file format.

Answer (score 0):

Appendix G of the PDF Specification gives examples that demonstrate use of the Page object.

Comment: No, I don't think we're speaking the same language. There is a Page Object, yes, but this question is about the structure tree, and how to define a Page as an item in the structure tree. The Page Tree and the Structure Tree are two different animals.

Comment: What do you mean by 'structure tree'?  Can you point me to the pages in the manual where that is referred to?  A PDF is simply a collection of objects organized by the xref table.

Comment: Soemtimes it has more than the xref table. Please see Chapter 10 (and Section 10.6) of the PDF Spec (link above)

Comment: It looks like you can't specify pages unless your referring to the content of a structure item like paragraphs.  A paragraphs content could be set to refer to page 4's content stream etc.. In this respect it seems more like HTML or a markup language allowing you to specify attributes for the various grouping elements like /spaceafter or /spacebefore or /pagebreakafter etc... So the StructureTree organizes the content of the PageTree using marked content sequences to "markup" the page content.  In this regard you wouldn't need page elements.  You don't see page elements in HTML?

Answer (score 0):

The PDF has a tree structure (which is what allows it to load any page so fast). The content does not have any structure unless you choose to use the marked content feature of the format which then allows metadata to be include in the data.